# Run timer error 13 VBA Macro Excel 'type mismatch'

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to do a few simple cell counts and the if statement i'm using is getting a runtime error.

`h` (integer)is equal to `0`

`y` (String) is equal to `"LD"` (which is what it's counting)

i'm asking it if the cell is not `0` then run the count

`(E6:E12)` Is where its counting into `E15`

```
If ("E15" <> h) Then ' The runtime error is on this line
Range("E15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E6:E12"), y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is straightforward, you're using the `<>` operator to compare the string value `"E15"` to an integer value, this is a nonsensical operation in VBA as strings cannot be compared directly to numbers.

I believe your *intention* is to get the **value of the cell E15**  and then compare that to zero. To do that your code should look like this:

```
Dim e15CellValue
e15CellValue = Cells.Item( 15, "E" ).Value
```

VBA has the concept of "default properties" so that can be abbreviated down to just:

```
Cells( 15, "E" )
```

So:

```
If Cells( 15, "E" ) <> h Then
     ' do stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Sub Test()

    Const h As Integer = 0
    Const y As String = "LD"

    If Range("E15").Value <> h Then
        Range("E15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E6:E12"), y)
    End If

End Sub
```